# Error: Module not found : daily.transaction

Tags: python, odoo

[Error Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3bW2.png)
Python File:

```
from . import field,osv

class daily_transaction(osv.osv):
        _name = 'daily.transaction'
        _description = 'Daily Transaction'
        _columns = {

                'subject': fields.char('Subject', size=128, required = True),
                'data' : fields.data('Date', required = True),
                'note': fields.text('Notes'),
                'amount': fields.float('Amount', required = True),
                'type' : fields.selection([
                        ('transport','Transport'),
                        ('household','Household'),
                        ('personal','Personal'),
                        ],
                        'Type', required = True),
                        }
```

I guess the **error** is in importing osv.

The error say's :
Module not Found : daily.transaction and I have also checked the indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not import your Python code into the `__init__.py`. Let's say you wrote that code in some daily_transaction.py file. You have to have

```
import daily_transaction
```

in your `__init__.py`.

By the way you should use

```
from openerp import fields, osv
# instead of
from . import field,osv
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using Odoo version 10, and you are trying to create model and fields with old API,
so you should create it with new API.

For example : to create new model and fields you can write as following in Odoo 10.

```
from odoo import models, fields

class daily_transaction(models.Model):
    _name = 'daily.transaction'
    _description = 'Daily Transaction'

    subject = fields.Char('Subject', size=128, required = True)
```

For more information you can refer [Odoo Documentation](http://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/howtos/backend.html#object-relational-mapping)